# Is there a way to compare two pages within the same google-sites site?

Tags: html, google-sites

We're using Google sites as a wiki.
Some people when they create a site for their project want to re-use pages from another project. I want to be able to see if the content of two pages is identical so that I can consolidate these pages.

I have found some services that take URL's and compare the pages, but I cannot use them as the pages are not accessible publicly. I'm also not comfortable in exposing the non-public URL to a third party.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [Change Detection](https://www.changedetection.com/comparepages.html) which is a tool that allows you to determine the text difference between any two HTML pages.

To use it simply paste the URLs from the two sites and it will tell you whether the pages are identical or not.

Additionally if you do a search for "Compare HTML Pages" you should be able to find some tools to help you with this.